# what is the difference between setprefwidth() and setmaxwidth()?

Tags: java, javafx-2

What is the basic difference ?

When I do like this

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setPrefWidth(50);
button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

any one will think that the button will be shown with width 50 and can be expandable up to infinite  , but what,s happening is the button occupies the total width of the screen .

Does any one know what's  their intention?

my border pane code :

```
borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
            borderPane.setCenter(button);
            borderPane.getStyleClass().add("bpane");

            //Region region = (Region) anyNode;
            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
```

Comment: What is the Layout containing the Button?

Comment: Have you called [`Window.pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29)?

Comment: Hi mwerchy , is there a pack method in stage class? or in Window class?

Comment: HI Aaron , i usedd a BorderPane Layout? soryy was not clear .

Comment: if you set maxwidth to 100 the button is max 100 in width.
but if you set MAX_VALUE then the buttons width is what he gets.